# How to generate receiver name in email body outlook?

Tags: configuration, outlook

Is there any way to set receiver's name automatically in mail body in outlook as we define the outlook signature?

i.e: If I am going to reply **Smith ABCD** then I want to start body as **Hi Smith**

Comment: I'm not sure if you achieve it by using VBA?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is.

You need to initialize your object from Active Directory.  Once you have it you should be able to get the FirstName as a property of that object.

Comment: I want to do this in outlook.How can I initialize object from Active Directory as you metioned?

Comment: What language are you doing this in?

Comment: As mentioned in the question I am looking for solution in outlook. Not using specific language.

Comment: I believe you are going to need a macro of some sort to do it this way.  Let me look a little further.